# How to know when a user was last active?

Tags: react-admin

Trying to build an auto-logout feature, and have got a timer going but looking for a way to start/restart the timer based on user's last active time.

The scenario is that the user has been away from their keyboard for X amount of time, and we want to log them out.

*Adding the code I've come up with since then:*

```js
// main.js
import React from 'react'
import { Admin } from 'react-admin'
import authProvider from '../../auth-provider'
import restClient from '../../rest-client'
import buildResources from './build-resources'
import { setLastActive } from './last-active'

const customReducers = {
  lastActive,
}

function lastActive() {
  const now = Date.now()
  setLastActive(now)

  return now
}

export const Main = () => (
  <Admin
    authProvider={authProvider}
    dataProvider={restClient}
    customReducers={customReducers}
  >
    {buildResources}
  </Admin>
)

// last-active.js
let lastActive

export const setLastActive = (timestamp = Date.now()) =>
  (lastActive = timestamp)

export const getLastActive = () => lastActive || null
```

It's not all the code, but enough to show the gist. I can know use the redux store, or the singleton to grab when they were last active. It's a bit flawed since **most, not all** actions go through the redux store.

Comment: You might want to demonstrate what you have tried before someone can answer the question. Good question recommendations on SO mention that you have to prove you have tried something.

Comment: Was kinda of hoping for an official solution that wasn't yet documented.
I ended up giving it a messy shot, and got it working somewhat close to being production ready.

I think to get to where I really need to be, I'll need to put up a PR to get in the library and be able to use the Providers directly.

Answer (score 0):

> `react-admin` works well with API-structured Apps.

Based on that fact, am assuming your `App` consumes endpoints (a lot!!).
Here's a possible process to auto-logout a user.

- Set the `token` in `authProvider.login` method
- Within your `authprovider.checkError` method, use `setTimeout` method to clear the `token`. This timeout can be based on last `CRUD` method executed.
- Once the `token` is cleared, `react-admin` redirects the user to `logout`.
  Thus requiring the user to re-login.